# Carousel works when there are 3 or more slides, but is broken when only 2 slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I built a minimal carousel that seems to work fine when there are 3 or more slides, but once I remove some slides, things begin to break. Some things I noticed were:

1. It removes the sliding animation on 'next'
2. It will make my divs flicker
3. It will break the animation completely

I worked on some possible solutions that deal with `.clone()` on the first slide, then `.append()` to the end of the container, and that makes it work somewhat, however it usually will only make 1 rotation and then be stuck on slide2.

**Here is my logic that handles clicking the prev/next buttons**

```
var before_clone = $(elm + ':first').clone();
var after_clone = $(elm + ':last').clone();
$('#buttons a').click(function(e) {
    //slide the item
    if (container.is(':animated')) {
        return false;
    }
    if (e.target.id == previous) {
        container.stop().animate({
            'left': 0
        }, 1500, function() {
            //container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
            container.append(after_clone);
            container.find(elm + ':last');
            resetSlides();
        });
    }
    if (e.target.id == next) {
        container.stop().animate({
            'left': item_width * -1
        }, 1500, function() {
            //container.find(elm + ':last').after(container.find(elm + ':first'));
            container.append(before_clone);
            container.find(elm + ':first');
            resetSlides();
        });
    }
    //cancel the link behavior            
    return false;
});
```

**and here is my logic that handles the automatic animations**

```
function rotate() {
    $('#next').click();
      container.append(before_clone);
      container.append(after_clone)
}
```

---

**Here are two fiddles as well for helping diagnose my problem**

**[my current attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/tLhgj4f9/10/)**

**[my original code(make sure to remove/comment out 2 of the lis)](https://jsfiddle.net/tLhgj4f9/1/)**

Appreciate any help you can provide to solve this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tLhgj4f9/13/) fiddle.

I changed your `next` to the following:

```
  if (e.target.id == next) {
    container.find(elm + ':last').after(container.find(elm + ':first'));
    container.css({
      'left': 0
    });
    container.stop().animate({
      'left': item_width * -1
    }, 1500, function () {
      resetSlides();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Well I'll be damned. Thanks so much for the help, this is perfect!